# flowplayer cannot be fullscreen in ie browser

Tags: flowplayer

but it work well in chrome and firefox.
this is my code :

```
<script>
        $f("player", "http://www.practice.com/ci/resource/flowplayer-3.2.9.swf", {
          plugins: {
            controls : {
                fullscreen : true,
            }
          },
          clip: {
            baseUrl: "http://www.practice.com/ci/resource",
            url: "info.flv",
            //urlResolvers: "secure",
            //scaling: "fit",
            onStart: function (clip) {
              document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = clip.baseUrl + "/" + clip.url;
            }
          }
        });
    </script>
```

is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `fullscreen : true` inside the `clip` and not within the `controls` in the `plugin` and see.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error at (the comma is wrong):

```
fullscreen : true
```